# Does the Count for Questions posted decrease at times

Tags: discussion, questions

I am not sure if I was looking at it properly, but as of writing this, post count is: **1,464,644**. I think I may have seen a larger figure few days back, something like, **15....**.

I know that posts get closed, but there is always a reference to those and we can view them. Is there some kind of mechanisms that completely removes incorrect posts and hence a decrease in post count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain posts which are poorly framed, and/or offtopic tend to be deleted by Moderators and/or High-rep users. In addition, there are couple of background processes which delete old posts [meeting certain criteria:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

> - less than (question age in days * 1.5) views
> - 0 score or lower
> - no answers
> - 1 comment or less
> - asked more than 365 days ago

In addition unanswered, negatively voted questions with zero answers are also deleted after 30 days.